# Weird entries in access logs

Tags: scripting, javascript, logging

2-5 times per day my web server gets the same number of requests, and the same requests, but appears to have no impact on.. anything.

The requests are here http://pastebin.com/3J6FUNr9

It looks like a substr of each of the javascript files, but what would the script be looking for doing so? The user agent is Java, the requests all happen in under a minute, and are always identical.

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Similarly we're getting http://paste.ubuntu.com/5783056/ . User-agent Java/1.7.0_21 among other more normal-looking ones, no referrers. Are you running the 3rd party Uservoice feedback script or something similar by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Your remote agent corrupted some query parameters and is sending you junk.

I used to see things like that a lot.  Flash apps were notorious for corrupting URLs.

It means that some end user isn't getting the experience they were hoping for.

Are you able to track down the user?

Comment: It comes from many anonymous users, as well as some users we can track down. The only flash we use is for Uploadify, and this doesnt happen while using the uploader, rather in the background while doing other things..